# MeshLab 32bit version

Tags: meshlab

I'm looking to download MeshLab 32bit version. Currently I support an environment that has a mixed environment of 32bit and 64bit devices.
I was able to downlaod Meshlab off their website, but this turned out to be a 64bit version only. Please provide me with a link to download the 32bit version.
Thank you.

Comment: This is not a question that would be useful to other users of meshlab, but just for you. Also, it is impossible to give you a link because you didn't post what is your operative system.

Comment: As stated, i work at a company that has both 32bit and 64bit devices. We deploy applications through sccm, therefore I require both the 32bit and 64bit version of Meshlab. From the website, I was able to only download the 64bit version. Please assist. Thank you.

Comment: Windows or Linux?

Comment: Sorry about that, its for Windows - Thanks.

Comment: The easier is to use the 1.3.3 version, which is still in the original meshlab page. https://sourceforge.net/projects/meshlab/files/meshlab/MeshLab%20v1.3.3/

Answer (score 0):

You still can get the 1.3.3 version for both 32-bits and 64-bits from the original meshlab page

https://sourceforge.net/projects/meshlab/files/meshlab/MeshLab%20v1.3.3/